# How to check whether the user completed their missions?

Tags: javascript, events, node.js, achievements

I am working on a coding/gaming application.
I am currently stuck in the **daily missions** part.

So, the user receives some missions each day, such as solving a problem, following another user, or completing a quiz that, they have to complete.

The problem is, I didn't know how to listen for mission completion?
How will I know **whether the user completed their missions or not**?

Here's a solution I thought of, however, I highly doubt that it is good:

Every time the user completes a certain task, I check whether they had that task as a daily mission. If positive, I'll mark that mission as complete.

Something like:

```
onProblemSolve(){
   const missions = this.currentUser.getMissions();
   if(missions.contains('problemSolving')) {
       this.markMissionAsComplete();
   }
}
```

Comment: Firing an event that the user has done a certain action (quiz, puzzle, following, etc) and your daily mission part is listening to all those events. If it contains this day one of them, mark as done. (There could be days where doing a quiz is not a daily mission). On startup and/ or loading the daily mission page doing extra query if possible against your db (like has solved 5 puzzles today) since probably not all your actions will leave a footprint in the db

Comment: @Zibelas, want to post that as an Answer below?

Comment: So, if I understood correctly I should fire an event for every action the user makes. And if it is a daily mission, I'll make ot as complete?

Comment: You might find this [article on the Observer Pattern](https://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html) useful. Your case is quite similar to the example of an achievement system that Nystrom uses to motivate the pattern.

Comment: thank you @DMGregory I'll check the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking if a puzzle is part of a daily quest, you could fire an event once the puzzle is done. Your daily quests can listen to this event and if  there is a quest that involves solving a puzzle, you mark it done. This has a few benefits. You can have an achievement system next to your daily quests and do not need to do much more code changes. If you have the logic on the puzzles side (as your snippet), you would have the same code again to mark an achievement. But if your achievement system just listens on puzzle done, nothing needs to change on the puzzle part. Why would your puzzle even care, if it is needed for a daily quest or achievement?

As a fallback, you should not only count on the event but involve your database as well. That does not mean that every event should write itself to it. Things like puzzle done would probably not only write "Level xy done" but when exactly with some extra stats like how many tries, time, hints, points and whatever your game offers. When you start your game, you can do a query for things like "has x puzzle done today". You do not want to call your database with this the whole time for performance reasons, but once at startup could be fine (or when loading your quest menu).

As DMGregory pointed out, the [Observer Pattern](https://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html) is your friend. There is always more than one way how you can do something but for most things, someone did it already and there is a pattern for it.

Comment: One advantage here is that your "Complete a Puzzle" daily mission can subscribe to just the "Puzzle Completed" event - so when the player does anything that *isn't* completing a puzzle, you don't even have to check it. Similarly your "Follow Another User" mission can listen to the "Follow List Changed" event, and stay out of the flow of handling puzzle completion.